# Pull elements out of two arrays to make a "flat" item list

Tags: json, transactions, jolt

I need to merge array data from two different arrays from the Input JSON and make a flat list of items in the Output JSON.  The first array contains the key required for the output and the second array contains the value.

So far, all my attempts at a spec haven't even come close, which is why I haven't listed one.  Please see the *Input* and Desired *Output* below.  Thanks for any help!!

**Input JSON :**

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "2": {
        "value": "DC1"
      },
      "3": {
        "value": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "2": {
        "value": "DC2"
      },
      "3": {
        "value": 10
      }
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "DataCenter",
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "label": "CCount",
      "type": "numeric"
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "numFields": 2,
    "numRecords": 2,
    "skip": 0,
    "totalRecords": 2
  }
}
```

**Desired Output JSON:**

```json
[
  {
    "DataCenter": "DC1",
    "CCount": "5"
  },
  {
    "DataCenter": "DC2",
    "CCount": "10"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might reciprocally match **id** value of `fields` array vs. the object keys of the `data` array within a common object within the first **shift** transformation spec in order to prepare for the second one in which we tile the attributes into their individual objects such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // represents the node for both "data" and "fields" arrays
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "value": "&1.&",
            "@1,label": "@2,id.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": {
          "*": "[&].@2,label"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Hi @MarcusO'Connor . Kindly you can upvote as well, since it increments my Jolt score in order to reach the tag badge aim, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": "&",
      "fields": {
        "*": {
          "label": "fields.@(1,id)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&2].@(4,fields.&1)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

In your desired output `CCount` value is a string, You can add the below spec to change an integer to a string.

```json
,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "CCount": "=toString"
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Barbos and MohammadReza, both your answers were exactly what I needed!